# Prove sequence is contractive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{3}x_{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n-2}$ for $n>2$, with $x_1 < x_2$. Prove that $x_n$ is convergent. The approach I'm using is by showing that $x_n$ is contractive. Here's how I do it:

$$x_3 = \frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{2}{3}x_1$$
$$x_4 = \frac{1}{3}x_3+\frac{2}{3}x_2$$

Thus $x_4-x_3=-\frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{2}{3}x_1-\frac{1}{3}x_3\le -\frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{2}{3}x_2-\frac{1}{3}x_3$ (since $x_1<x_2$). Hence, $\left|x_4-x_3\right|\le \frac{1}{3}\left|x_3-x_2\right|\le \frac{2}{3}\left|x_3-x_2\right|$ (base case).

Inductive hypothesis: $\left|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right|\le \left(\frac{2^n}{3^{n-1}}\right)\left|x_3-x_2 \right|$

$\implies \left|x_{n+3}-x_{n+2}\right|=\left| \frac{1}{3}x_{n+2}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{3}x_{n+1}-\frac{2}{3}x_n \right|\le \frac{1}{3}\left|  x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right|+\frac{2}{3}\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|\le \frac{2}{3}\left|  x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right|+\frac{2}{3}\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|\le \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left|  x_{3}-x_{2}\right|+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left|  x_{3}-x_{2}\right|\le\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left|  x_{3}-x_{2}\right|+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left|  x_{3}-x_{2}\right|\le \left(\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^n}\right)\left|  x_{3}-x_{2}\right|$.

Hence, $x_n$ is contractive, which implies that it converges.

Please let me now if my proof is OK.

Comment: You cannot conclude $|x_4-x_3|\le \frac 13|x_3-x_2|$ from $x_4-x_3\le \frac 13(x_2-x_3)$.

Comment: Note that  

$$x_n=\frac13x_{n-1}+\frac23x_{n-2}\implies x_{n}-x_{n-1}=-\frac23(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}) \tag 1$$

where we have from $(1)$ 

$$|x_n-x_{n-1}|=\frac23|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|$$